# HighChart/HighStock not showing closest tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having this wired tooltip hover problem. It basically feels like HighStock is showing the wrong tooltip when you are close to the edge of the chart.

If you hoover in the middle of the chart, it's spot on. The closer you come to the edge, the more "off" it gets.

I see there are a `rect.highchart-data-label-box` overlay around the points, that are pretty close to the mouse position in question, but it still shouldn't take preference of the box I'm inside of with the mouse button in the same given moment?

[View this screencast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMqJy6UFpGdhOeXbHpLssGT6N_ezPey7/view)

1. You will see I have the mouse pointer directly outside of the chart (to the left) – fair enough, it snaps to the closest point(s).
2. Then I move the mouse pointer direct on the first set of points on the Y-axix – it should still snap to the closest point(s)?

> I've tried setting `snap` to zero, tried setting `shared` to false, among other things.

Have anyone have the same or similar problem? Suggestions on what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Mille, more precise description and an live example would be very useful in this case.

Comment: You are right. I've updated the post with a screencast!

Comment: I mean live example on jsfiddle and your chart options. This problem does not seem to occur in general, so probably is related with your chart options or styles.